# Launch exe file generated by Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app

I need to get a runnable .exe file from a simple Windows 10 universal app developed in VisualStudio 2015 community edition. 
This worked before on a windows 7 PC with Visual Studio 2012 (or maybe 2013), the .exe was located at MyProject/bin/x64/Debug, and I was able to run it.

Now, with Visual Studio 2015, I can still find the .exe file, but it gives me an error when I try to run it:

> This application can only run in the context of an app container.

Is there a way to export an executable, without having a payed developer account?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's a windows 10 universal app then you cannot run it with a exe file. You need to create the appxupload binary in visual studio. Here's the steps to follow to create the binaries.

Open the solution

Select Project-->Store-->Create App Packages

A dialog opens and select 'No' if you want to generate appx file for your own use. Then click next.
In the next screen select create after checking the appropriate requirements.

Hope this helps your case. Check these links for screenshots.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/64fvm3huy64qqda/Capture.jpg?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/hw52n281u7rse1z/Capture1.jpg?dl=0